# How to reduce runtime for Lambda function that reads JSON and puts data in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My Lambda function does a get request to a JSON api and puts the data in DynamoDB. However, it takes way too long run, because the JSON is quite large. How can I adjust my code so that my runtime reduces? Or can I adjust my DynamoDB settings to make the write process work faster?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const data = await httprequest();

         for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
         var iden = Date.now();
        var identifier = iden.toString();

            var params = {
            Item: {
                ID: identifier,           
                journal: data.d.results[i].journal
            },

            TableName: ''test"
        };

        await docClient.put(params).promise();

        }


        console.log('Document inserted.');

        return JSON.stringify(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);

        return err;
    }
};
```

Comment: DynamoDB read/write capacity is configurable, so you can increase a table's write performance. Hopefully your partition key is the journal, not the timestamp. And, of course, use batched writes.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, will do! What's the problem with using timestamp as a partition key?

Comment: Timestamps have a tendency to cluster, causing reads/writes to be poorly distributed across the shards of a NoSQL database. Having a more uniform distribution of partition keys allows greater parallelization. Plus you can't typically query timestamps. And it's possible to accidentally have the same timestamp for multiple very-close-in-time consecutive writes, which means that if the sort key you're using across those multiple items doesn't change then you are actually updating existing items instead of writing new items.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of inserting your data 1 by 1, consider writing in batch. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

> The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped!